# How can I define a string (contain space) array in gnuplot?

Tags: arrays, gnuplot

I know how to define a string array without space in gnuplot, for instance,

```
titles = "LineA LineB"
```

**How can I define a string array where the string contains a space, such as `Line A`?** Here is the source code but it doesn't work.

```
titles = "'Line A' 'Line B'"

set style line 1 pt 2 lc rgb 'green'
set style line 2 pt 4 lc rgb 'red'

plot for [i = 1:words(titles)] file using 2:3 with lp ls i title word(titles, i)
```

PS: the version of my gnuplot is:

```
G N U P L O T
Version 4.6 patchlevel 4    last modified 2013-10-02 
Build System: Linux x86_64
```

Comment: With gnuplot version 4.6. this isn't possible, with 5.0 the variant you show works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Christoph in the comment, gnuplot **4.6** is impossible but **5.0** supports this operation.

To install gnuplot 5.0, download the source file from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/), and then:

```
#decompress it:
tar -xvf gnuplot-5.0.1.tar.gz

#install the dependency libraries for cairo-based terminals, like pdfcairo
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev
sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-dev


#build it:
cd gnuplot-5.0.1 
./configure 
make

#test it:
＃make check

#install it:
sudo make install
```

For more info, refer to [GNUPLOT Version 5.0.1 Release Notes](http://gnuplot.info/ReleaseNotes_5_0_1.html).

```
$ gnuplot

    G N U P L O T
    Version 5.0 patchlevel 1    last modified 2015-06-07 

    Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2015
    Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

    gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
    faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
    immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

Terminal type set to 'x11'
gnuplot>
```

Comment: You'll be left with very few terminals if you just do this. Check on the last page of the output of ./configure which ones are missing, and install the -dev package of the respective libraries, e.g. libgd, cairo, pango, qt, etc. A short google search should help there.

Comment: ＠Karl Ratzsch. You are right. I have edited my answer. For more info, pls refer to another question [pdfcairo 'unknown or ambiguous terminal type' in gnuplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31655291/pdfcairo-unknown-or-ambiguous-terminal-type-in-gnuplot).

Comment: Well, that's for the cairo-based non-interactive terminals. And how do you know the user is on a debian-based system?

Comment: @KarlRatzsch I answer my question after figuring out.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice you also asked the original question. Btw., debian-backports (and so also ubuntu, and i guess other distributions) also has a readymade binary package of gnuplot 5.0. It's often better to use that instead of compiling yourself, because then you have all teminals working, including postscript, which is notoriously cumbersome to install correctly. Also wxt and qt can have some problems depending on the combination of library versions (qt4/5, wxt2.8/3.0, gtk+2/3 ...) and base system that are not so easy to sort out.